# Creating a WinForms custom container control with some non-removable controls

Tags: winforms, custom-controls

I've written a custom tab control (`FooTabControl`) which hosts specific tab page controls (`FooTabPage` instances). The `FooTabPage`s know to place themselves into a dedicated area within the `FooTabControl`.

Now I wish to have the `FooTabControl` also host a `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` child control (in another dedicated area of the `FooTabControl`). I want the user to be able to place his controls into this `Panel`, but disallow him from removing the `Panel` control itself (while still being able to add and remove `FooTabPage`s as he sees fit).

What would be the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override [CreateControlsInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrolsinstance.aspx) (in the custom control) and return you own implementation of [ControlCollection](http://implementation).
In your implementation your will override [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove.aspx) to disallow removing the Panel.